# PHP register clicks to callto: link

Tags: php

Is there any way of registering clicks to a callto: link with the use of PHP? I've set up a site for a friend of mine and what I would like to do is to create a log of some sort to show who called who eg. if the current user clicks the callto: link I'd like to add a row to the database like "userX called numberY at hh:mm" but I've noticed you cant set variables in the callto: link as you would in ordinary links with just appending $var1=val etc...

I figured you could make use of the onclick()-method of the a-tag but I'd rather skip javascript at the moment and just use PHP. Anyone got any ideas for this? Is it possible to use the header()-function and "redirect" to the callto: link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a proof of concept doing a redirect (in .NET), and it seems to work ok in Chrome, but it puts the following in FireFox (might be an artifact of .NET actually):

```
Object moved to here.
```

I guess you would do something like this:  The user clicks on link to /docall.php?callto=blahblah.  The contents of docall.php looks like this:

```
$callto = $_GET['callto'];
// log the call to $callto in the database

// send back the callto protocol response to the user.
header("location:callto:$callto");
```

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I'll give it a try and see if I can solve it with that method.

Comment: For me it works both in Chrome and FF, but not IE (surprise surprise!).  I think I'll go with this solution for now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

callto: is not http:, which means these links are not to be followed by a browser when you click them, but instead trigger activation of some program on the client computer associated with that protocol, right?

Which means no HTTP request is made, so you can't point them to a PHP script.

Which means the only way you're going to intercept these clicks is with JavaScript or by modifying the client software the browser launches itself.

Comment: Sorta, kinda, in some versions of some browsers, not including the most popular browser used by people still clicking NetMeeting protocol links, by a hack... no, your solution does not work.